# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurs when add annotation to MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to display annotations using lat and lon, the lat and lon are coming from JSON(nearbyStop), and i stored the longitude and latitude into two NSArrays. When i try to add annotation to the mapview in the for loop, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurs 
    [image]
Any helps?

```
    NSMutableArray *coordinateLongi = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *stop in nearbyStop) {
    NSString *longi = stop[@"result"][@"lon"];
    if(longi == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"there is no data");
    }
    else
    {
        [coordinateLongi addObject:longi];
    }
}

NSMutableArray *coordinateLatit = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *stop in nearbyStop) {
    NSString *latit = stop[@"result"][@"lat"];
    if(latit == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"there is no data");
    }
    else
    {
        [coordinateLatit addObject:latit];
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i<coordinateLongi.count;i++)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
    coord.latitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[coordinateLongi objectAtIndex:i]] floatValue];
    for(int j = 0; j<coordinateLatit.count;j++)
    {
        coord.longitude = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[coordinateLatit objectAtIndex:i]] floatValue];
    }


    CustomAnnotation *annotObj = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord title:@"title" ];
    [map addAnnotation:annotObj];//Error occurs here.
}
```

Here is my customAnnotation.h

```
 #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface CustomAnnotation : MKPlacemark
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateL;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *time;
}

@property (nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *subtitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *time;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c  title:(NSString *) t  subTitle:(NSString *)timed time:(NSString *)tim;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c title:(NSString *)tit;



@end
```

and customAnnotation.m

```
    #import "CustomAnnotation.h"

@implementation CustomAnnotation

@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;
@synthesize phone;
@synthesize time;
@synthesize coordinateL;


-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c  title:(NSString *) t  subTitle:(NSString *)timed time:(NSString *)tim
{
    self.coordinateL=c;
    self.time=tim;
    self.subtitle=timed;
    self.title=t;
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c title:(NSString *)tit
{
    self.coordinateL=c;
    self.title=tit;
    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the cause but this...

```
@interface CustomAnnotation : MKPlacemark
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateL;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *time;
}

@property (nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *subtitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *time;

etc..
```

can be reduced to

```
@interface CustomAnnotation : MKPlacemark

@property (nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateL;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *subtitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *time;

etc...
```

as theres no need to declare ivars for properties.

and these

```
@synthesize phone;
@synthesize time;
@synthesize coordinateL;
```

can be deleted as you dont need to synthesise properties unless they come from a protocol which `title` and `subtitle` do in `MKAnnotation` which `MKPlacemark` conforms to.

Im a little confused as to why you declare `coordinateL` when `MKPlacemark` already defines `coordinate`

the other probable problem is that you are not calling the superclass in your `init` methods.

so you probably need this in both your init methods...

```
-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord title:(NSString *)title
{
    self = [super initWithCoordinate:coord addressDictionary:nil];
    if(self) {
      self.coordinateL = coord;
      self.title = title;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Warren! I've already solved the problem. What i was doing is try to display different types of annotations on the map, that's why it confused me. One type is the nearby restaurants, I used MKLocalSearchRequest to search them and add annotations. Another type is nearby stops, I create another annotation with NSObject<MKAnnotation> super class and declare the coordinate. Now i figure out the different between NSObject<MKAnnotation> and MKPlacemark superclass :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that these lines are the problem:

`NSString *longi = stop[@"result"][@"lon"];`

and

`NSString *longi = stop[@"result"][@"lat"];`

because the variable `stop` is nil, OR the dictionary `stop[@"result"]` is nil.  Trying to get a value out of a nil dictionary is going to crash your app, but adding in a nil check for the dictionary (`stop` or `stop[@"result"]` in this case) should keep it from crashing, but will also give you the opportunity to do some error handling for improper dictionary state.

Comment: nah.. i used NSLog to inspect coordinateLatit and coordinateLongi NSArray. The lon and lat information are already there. But when addAnnovation, the error occurs